# Shifted first item in the output of package dirtree

Tags: dirtree

I used the dirtree package to display a directory structure, like in the example below

```
\dirtree{% 
.1 /.
.2 Directory1.
.3 Directory2.
.2 Directory3.
```

}

In the PDF output the first item is strangely shifted, like in the first image:
[image]

instead of being aligned with the rest of the items like in the second image:
[image]

I used dirtree always, and the output was always correct - I do not understand what is wrong now.

Comment: Could you provide a small but complete (i.e., compilable) document that shows this problem? The document should start with `\documentclass`, `\usepackage`s, `\begin{document}`, the `\dirtree` code, and `\end{document}`. This makes it easier for the community to reproduce the problem and provide a solution.

Comment: Alas, I cannot! As I started the document that made problems this morning, everything was OK again! So I am unable to make it repeatable. The code is below, but still, it does not make any problems any longer!

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=1.80cm, top=2.20cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\title{Synthetic Orthogonal Views}
\begin{document}
 \maketitle 
\section*{Something}  
 \dirtree{%
  .1 Company.
  .2 Divisions.
  .3 Core.
  .4 Solutions.
  .5 Math.
  .6 Code.
  .7 Binary.
  .8 Debug.
  .8 Release.
  .7 Solution.sln.
 }
\end{document}

Comment: Thanks for the code - please edit it into the question (using the `edit` button directly below the post).

Comment: Also: I tried the code, and I get the correct output. Can you confirm that you get the wrong output when using the code you just posted?

Comment: Marijn, no, the output from the attached code was correct for me, too. The error was not reproducible the other day. I do not know, after all, why it had happened.